# What are wrapper and veener functions? How to apply them in a system design?

Tags: java, uml, system, modeling

I looked for detailed information on wrappers and veeners. Looks like there are very few info about them. How can it be used in a design diagram or in Java?

Could someone explain me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Adapter or Wrapper (I've never heard anyone call it Verneer) is one of the Gang of Four Design Patterns.  Here's what it's for:

> Convert the interface of a class into
>   another interface clients expect.
>   Adapter lets classes work together
>   that couldn't otherwise because of
>   incompatible interfaces

Have a look at [this](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2008/cmsc433/lectures/designPatternsP1.pdf).

The definitive reference, now 15 years old, is the Gang of Four ["Design Patterns"](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_1_15?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=design+patterns&x=0&y=0&sprefix=design+patterns).